# $10$ students are randomly seated in a row. $3$ of these students are brothers. Find

Tags: probability

> $10$ students are randomly seated in a row. $3$ of these students are brothers.
>
> a) What is the probability that these students will sit next to each other?

The way I pictured it ,   b b b  s  s s s s s s

```
                     1   2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

grouped the brothers as 1.

Therefore,  $\dfrac{8!3!}{10!} = \dfrac{1}{15}$.

The $3!$ is the ways to rearrange the $3$ boys.

> b) What is the probability that exactly two of them will sit next to each other?

b b s b s s s s s s

s b b s s s b s s s

All I got so far is I must pick $2$ of those $3$, and $2!$ ways to rearrange them.

$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}2}{10!}$$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Yes. There are $8!\cdot 3!$ ways to arrange the ten individuals when the brothers are grouped three-together; your argument for this is sound.   Also a total of $10!$ ways to arrange the individuals with no such constraint.

Alternatively you could count ways to: arrange the three brothers, arrange the seven others, then select one from the eight spaces between-or-outside them to place the line of brothers.  $$3!~7!~\binom 81$$

Which, of course, has the same value.

(b) Use that alternative method.   Count ways to arrange the seven others, then ways to *select, arrange*, and place the brothers so that they are a pair and a singleton seperated by at least one other.

> All I got so far is I must pick $2$ of those $3$, and $2!$ ways to rearrange them.

$\checkmark$.    You have counted ways to *selected and arranged* the pair.   Now count the ways to arrange the seven others, place the pair in one from eight spaces, and place the lone brother in one from the remainder.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, so would it be [(3)(2)(7!)(8)(7)]/(10!)?.   select 2 out of 3 brothers, ways to arrange.  7! ways to arrange the non brothers, 8c1 ways to place the two brothers with the non brothers, and 7 ways to add the last brother so he is not next to the two others.

Comment: $\checkmark$ Otherwise written as: ${^3\mathrm P_2}{^7\mathrm P_7}{^8\mathrm P_2}/{^{10}\mathrm P_{10}}$